# Ionic: Why is my $localStorage based object array undefined on device?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework, ng-storage

I have a $localStorage based object array in a service:

```
.service('storedService', function($localStorage){

this.$storage = $localStorage;

this.$storage.storedItems;

this.addToList = function(item){

this.$storage.storedItems.push(item);

};

})
```

And the object array is used in a controller:

```
.controller('storedController', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $http,     $localStorage, itemListService, storedService) {

$scope.storedItems = storedService.$storage.storedItems;

$scope.showPopup = function() {

var i = 0;
//Pictures array stores 10 hits with URL of images
$scope.pictures = [];
//newitem is the new object pushed to items array
$scope.newitem = {}


$scope.getPic = function(name) {

    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDKzJO_2-a82Jrn0sA2oSnDgHORcJegCAA&cx=011061616694035020478:dvpxju__yje&searchType=image&lr=lang_no&q=' + name).then(function(resp) {
        console.log('Success', resp.data.items);
        $scope.pictures = resp.data.items;
        $scope.newitem.pic = resp.data.items[0].image.thumbnailLink;
    })

    $scope.changePic = function() {

        if (i == 10) {

            i = 0;

        } else {
            i++;
        }
        $scope.newitem.pic = $scope.pictures[i].image.thumbnailLink;

    }

}

var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<form ng-submit="getPic(newitem.name)"><input type="text" placeholder="Item name" ng-model="newitem.name" ng-blur="getPic(newitem.name)"></br><img alt="Press me!" src="{{newitem.pic}}" style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" ng-click="changePic()"></form>',
    title: 'Add new item to list',
    subTitle: 'Tip:Tap the image to change it',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel'
    }, {
        text: '<b>Save</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {
            storedService.addToList($scope.newitem);
        }
    }]
});
}

$scope.data = {

showDelete: false

};

$scope.moveToItems = function(item){

itemListService.addToList(item);

};


})
```

This takes an object and stores it in the object array. It all works good in the browser, but in Ionic View and on device it does not work. It shows up as undefined. Why is it not undefined in the browser? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is undefined? Please be more specific. Where do you set `storedItems` as array if it doesn't already exist in storage?

Comment: @charlietfl The object array. $storage.storedItems. If I do a $storage.storedItems = [] in the service I do not get the undefined problem, but my local storage is reset when the service is loaded and is basically made useless.

Comment: right...but you need to check if it is defined first, if not make it empty array. You can't push into `undefined`

Comment: `this` in a service is the service object that is injected into other components... nothing wrong there

Comment: @charlietfl But when I define it, either in the controller or in the service, it ends up resetting the local storage when I refresh and reuse the controller. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that if there is nothing currently stored in localStorage the `storedItems` is not an array and is undefined

When service initializes and you assign $storage, check if `storedItems` is defined and if not assign an empty array to it

```
this.$storage = $localStorage;
if(!this.$storage.storedItems){
   this.$storage.storedItems =[];
}
```

Comment: Off course. That makes sense. It works on iOS Emulator and when I build it on device. But for some reason it does not work when I use Ionic View. Testet on both iPad and iPhone. Do you have any theories on why?

Answer (score 0):

maybe devices are more slow than your browser. try wrap your code in `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () { //**code*/})`